# How to match "not followed by some literals" using regex?

Tags: regex

I want to match all the literals in the form **literal (** *-- i.e. : Literal followed by space, then opening parenthesis*. But if the literal is either of "hi" or "hello" or "bye", then it should not be matched.

So I am *looking for the following result* :

```
Literal     ::      Result
--------------------------------    
Hello (     ::      Match
There (     ::      Match
hello (     ::      Not Match
New (       ::      Match
hi (        ::      Not Match
```

I am trying to do it by lookahead regex. So I put like

```
(^|\s)(?!((hello|hi|bye)(\s\()))
```

But its matching all.

And I can't do it by lookbehind as it doesn't take regex expression.

Is there any regex to do this task?

**UPDATE**

I'm trying with **perl** and **checkstyle** *(Don't know which flavor checkstyle uses)*.

The **lookahead** is giving Match for both.
But in **lookbehind**, Perl is giving error  `Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<!(hello|hi|bye))\s\(/`,  whereas in checkstyle I'm getting desired result.

Comment: Using which regex flavor?

Comment: I don't understand "I can't do it by lookbehind as it doesn't take regex expression" - could you explain what you mean more fully please?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : I got that [from here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It says "that most regex flavors do not allow you to use just any regex inside a lookbehind, because they cannot apply a regular expression backwards."

Comment: @m.buettner : There is a problem too. I'm trying with perl and checkstyle (Don't know which flavor checkstyle uses). The lookahead is giving Match for both. But in lookbehind, Perl is giving error `Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<!(hello|hi|bye))\s\(/` , whereas in checkstyle I'm getting desired result.

Comment: But the paragraphs after that one then lay out what parts of regular expressions are supported by various engines - you haven't told us which one you're using, so I cannot comment further from there.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : I've updated my description part, if that helps. Sorry for incompleteness.

Comment: you can solve the variable-lookbehind problem, by extracting the alternation into three lookbehinds, like `(?:(?<!hello)(?<!hi)(?<!bye))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't work because it will always match the space between the literal and the `(` (since a space matches `(^|\s)` and `(` doesn't match `((hello|hi|bye)(\s\())`). And it should also match spaces at many other places.

[Test to show what yours matches](http://www.rubular.com/r/SdOPokRUJF).

This regex should work:

```
\b(?!(?:hello|hi|bye)\s)\w+\s\(
```

[Test for this regex](http://www.rubular.com/r/PuTl8zhVmO).

**Explanation:**

`\b` - word boundary.
`(?!(?:hello|hi|bye)\s)` - negative look-ahead for `hello`, `hi` or `bye` followed by a space.
It's followed by a space so we match `byelo (`, remove it if this is not desired.
`(?:hello|hi|bye)` as opposed to simply `(hello|hi|bye)` just makes it a non-capturing group, it doesn't change the output.
`\w+` - one or more word characters (word characters are typically `[A-Za-z0-9_]`).
`\s` - a space.
`\(` - a bracket.

Comment: The first link does, but that's OP's regex. The second link (my regex) matches correctly. Edited to clarify.

Comment: Yeah, didn't see the second link at first :P +1'd.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a perl-compatible `regex` engine you should be able to use a zero-width negative lookbehind assertion like this...

```
(?<!hello|hi|bye) \(
```

An example using R (with perl-compatability switched on)...

```
string <- c( "hello (" , "hi (" , "bye (" , "Hello (" , "Anything (" )
grepl( pattern = "(?<!hello|hi|bye) \\(" , string , perl = TRUE )
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

We can be a bit more precise like so....

```
^.+(?<!^hello|^hi|^bye)\s\(
```

Matching the start of the string, then optionally any characters, but not `hello`, `hi` or `bye` at the start of a string, then a space, then an open parentheses.

Comment: I'm getting this error in perl `Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<!hello|hi|bye) \(/ at x.pl line 19.`

Comment: @Panther I've modified slightly. Might helkp with your regex engine?.

Comment: This doesn't match, say, `Notbye (`.

Comment: @Junuxx thanks. I think this will work now. Are there other instances given the initial problem where this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is -

compressed:

```
 (?:^|(?<=\s))((?!(?:hello|hi|bye)\s\()[a-zA-Z]+\s\()
```

expanded:

```
 (?:
      ^ 
   |  (?<= \s )
 )
 (
      (?!
           (?: hello | hi | bye )
           \s \(
      )
      [a-zA-Z]+ \s \(
 )
```